# Cannot load ggmap package successfully in case of dashDB / R

Tags: r, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I tried to develop hands-on materials for R with dashDB.
I want to use ggmap package to work with geospatial data, so I typed "install.packages("ggmap")" on RStudio provided by Bluemix.

I got the following result. I found the pre-installed package "ggplot" was older than that ggmap required.

```
install.packages("ggmap")
:
Loading required package: rpart
Loading required package: rpart.plot
Loading required package: ggplot2
* installing *source* package ‘ggmap’ ...
** package ‘ggmap’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : package ‘ggplot2’ 1.0.1 is loaded, but >= 2.0.0 is required by ‘ggmap’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggmap’
* removing ‘/mnt/blumeta0/home/dash101482/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/ggmap’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggmap’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmps0c2yk/downloaded_packages’
```

Cloud anyone please tell me how to solve or avoid this error?

Comment: It is right there: `Error : package ‘ggplot2’ 1.0.1 is loaded, but >= 2.0.0 is required`. You need a newer ggplot2.

Comment: Yes, just update ggplo2 via install.packages("ggplot2").

Comment: FYI, there is also an alternative method of running RStudio in Bluemix with dashDB: You can instantiate an RStudio docker container in Bluenix ready to work with dashDB: https://github.com/ibmdbanalytics/dashdb_analytic_tools

This way you have full control over the underlying system image.

Comment: Hi, I tried to update ggplot2 by issuing install.packages("ggplot2"), but 'Error: package ‘ggplot2’ is required by ‘ibmdbR’ so will not be detached' was shown. I'll look into how to detach ‘ibmdbR’.

Comment: I also tried to use docker, but connecting to iwm.dhe.ibm.com was failed (ERROR: 403: Forbidden). Is there any way to avoid 403 error?